Safe quoting of TeamCity parameters in Python scripts
TeamCity allows build parameters to be defined, and then used in build scripts.
Eg define a parameter output_dir which is set to doc\release_notes. TeamCity documentation says to use it in build scripts with % escapes, eg %output_dir%.
But, how can such parameters be safely used in Python build scripts without being messed up by various characters?
Eg if the Python build script has
output_dir = "%output_dir%"

Then various characters in the build parameter can cause problems.

\ will be treated as an escape character, so doc\release_notes becomes two lines, doc and elease_notes separated by a CR character \r.
A trailing \ will "escape" the closing quote, so for release_notes\ the Python interpreter will generate a syntax error, saying the string "release_notes\" is unterminated.
A double-quote character will prematurely terminate the string, so 9" nails will be seen by Python as the string "9" followed by a syntax error.

Using a Python "raw string literal", eg
output_dir = r"%output_dir%"

solves (1) but not (2) or (3).
Using a Python "raw string multi-line literal", eg
output_dir = r"""%output_dir%"""

solves (1), but not (2), and solves (3) except if the " character is at the end of the string.
How can TeamCity build parameters be safely used in Python build scripts without being messed up by various string escape character issues?
